# Looking for a way to have classes auto register themselves as an Endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

I'm transforming a .NET Framework 4.8 web application that was built around Generic Handlers into a .NET Core 3.1 web application.

I'm looking for a way for each of my custom page classes to be able to auto-register themselves as an Endpoint during the Startup phase. Right now its a manual process which I'd like to simplify.

This is what I'm working with so far.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

namespace App
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(StaticFolder("/Resources"));
            app.UseStaticFiles(StaticFolder("/Clients"));

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/", Page<Default>);

                endpoints.MapGet("/Login.ashx", Page<Login>);
                endpoints.MapPost("/LoginPostBack.ashx", Page<LoginPostBack>);
                endpoints.MapGet("/Logout.ashx", Page<Logout>);
                endpoints.MapPost("/LogoutPostBack.ashx", Page<LogoutPostBack>);

                endpoints.MapGet("/Clients/", Page<Clients.Default>);
                endpoints.MapPost("/Clients/", Page<Clients.DefaultPostBack>);
                endpoints.MapGet("/Clients/Add.ashx", Page<Clients.Add>);
                endpoints.MapPost("/Clients/AddPostBack.ashx", Page<Clients.AddPostBack>);
                endpoints.MapGet("/Clients/Modify.ashx", Page<Clients.Modify>);
                endpoints.MapPost("/Clients/ModifyPostBack.ashx", Page<Clients.ModifyPostBack>);
                endpoints.MapGet("/Clients/Delete.ashx", Page<Clients.Delete>);
                endpoints.MapPost("/Clients/DeletePostBack.ashx", Page<Clients.DeletePostBack>);
            });
        }

        private async Task Page<T>(HttpContext context) where T : new()
        {
            T page = new T();
            await ((IPage)page).ProcessRequest(context);
        }

        private StaticFileOptions StaticFolder(string path)
        {
            return new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), path.Substring(1))),
                RequestPath = path
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Below is an example of a custom page class:

```
using System.Web;

namespace App
{
    public class Default : FormPage
    {
        protected override void PreProcess()
        {
            Page.Icon = "far fa-home";
            Page.Title = "Home";
        }

        protected override void Process()
        {
            Write(@"<div class=""row mb-4"">");

            Write(@"<div class=""col-12"">");
            Write(@"<h5>Home</h5>");
            Write(@"</div>");

            Write(@"</div>");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using reflection:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    foreach (Type pageType in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes)
        if (typeof(IPage).IsAssignableFrom(pageType))
        {
            IPage pageInstance = (IPage)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);

            MethodInfo pageMethod = typeof(Startup).GetMethod("Page");
            MethodInfo delegateMethod = pageMethod.MakeGenericMethod(pageType);
            RequestDelegate requestDelegate = (RequestDelegate)RequestDelegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(RequestDelegate), this, delegateMethod);

            endpoints.MapGet(pageInstance.Endpoint, requestDelegate);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you're trying to maintain URLs ending in `ashx`, even though that has no meaning in ASP.NET Core. Razor Pages have default conventions for how the URLs are structured, which pretty much lines up with your URLs here, aside from the `ashx`.

If you're just trying to maintain your existing URL structure (no 404s), the correct thing to do here is to create permanent redirects, e.g. `Login.ashx` to just `Login`. Then, the default convention-based routing would just work, and if someone did go to the old URL, they'll just get redirected to the new one.

Comment: The .ashx extensions are just temporary. Once I have the application fully migrated, the .ashx will be dropped. Using Razor pages isn't an option. These are custom page classes that output HTML directly to the response body. Its an entire custom framework that's been internally developped. I've updated the question with a sample page.

Comment: Well, you've gutted the entire framework here, aside from the endpoint routing, and then complaining that you have to handle all the routing manually. Of course? It doesn't have to be Razor Pages; MVC can work as well. Either has convention-based routing that prevents you from having to define endpoints en masse. What is it that you can't be solved with existing ASP.NET Core application patterns. At a certain point, it's pointless to even be using the framework. You're going to have to reimplement authorization, and all kinds of other framework components going down this path.

Comment: I'm well aware that the entire ASP.NET pipeline is being bypassed, its required for this particular design scenario. Everything is already handled internally (including things such as Authorization). I wouldn't have to be going down this path if .NET Standard 2.1 libraries were compatible with the .NET Framework 4.8, but unfortunately Microsoft took the decision to [end compatibility at .NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard).